# Bad plots in python, good plots in excel

Tags: equities, programming, time-series, graphs

I am wondering if you could solve the mystery about why matplotlib / seaborn give me a line plot of the IBM stock price, which is terrible as you can see below, with some vertical lines that are of unknown origin,  while excel gives me a very good and nice line plot . I am using the same .csv file in both cases, and the latest python/ matplotlib versions. The csv file has the IBM stock price, which I downloaded from the internet.  What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Below is the excel plot :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the dates in your `DataFrame` (they're all parsed as the first day of a month), it appears that you need to add `dayfirst=True` in your `read_csv` statement.

Answer (score 0):

while reading the file in pandas do this:

df = pd.read_csv('IBMclose.csv', parse_dates= ['Date'], infer_datetime_format= True)

Its just not reading the date right.

If True and parse_dates is enabled, pandas will attempt to infer the format of the datetime strings in the columns, and if it can be inferred, switch to a faster method of parsing them. In some cases this can increase the parsing speed by 5-10x.